Integrals of cubic function in geometry
For a shape given with an expression $$f(x,y,z)=|x|^2+|y|^2+|z|^2+b(|x|^3+|y|^3+|z|^3)=R^2,$$ where $0 \leqslant b \leqslant 3$ is the free parameter of the shape and $R>0$ is the radius, I am looking to find an analytical solution of the volume, surface area and cap parameters (for a given value of plane $z=a<z_{max}$ above which the cap is defined) such as cap volume, cap surface area and cap base area. Tools which could obtain an analytical expression, such as Mathematica, are also welcomed.
I know that i cannot use the perturbative expansion for $b$, since in general, for my problem, it assumes the values around 2. Any kind of help would be highly appreciated since this problem has been bothering me for a long time, and I'm posting here only after I have tried many things, so far unsuccessfully.
Thank you in advance.
EDIT : Forgot to add the absolute signs.
EDIT 2 : In general, I could ask how do you analytically calculate the volume or surface area of the body defined by the general third degree polynomial.

The function does not define a closed volume. Take for example $z=0$ and plot $x^2+y^2+x^3+y^3=1$.

@Andrei , my mistake, I forgot to add absolute value. I accidentally used the form without absolute values because I was calculating the volume in the first octant.
